# How do I add an additional Path to my Canopy Paths?

Tags: python, windows-8.1, enthought, canopy

I have created modules and want to preferably save them in a folder which can be access by multiple computers (but getting it saved in the correct location for canopy to access regardless of what folder I am in would work also)

I know how to do both on a Unix system however I am working on a Windows 8.1 computer and am not sure how to modify the Path with additional paths nor which file path to save for Canopy to read anywhere.  I have read all of the questions regarding canopy and modules on here and tries the suggestions with the Esri examples but they do not seem to work (paths are different) others are showing Mac OS commands.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

On any OS, setting/modifying the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable may be the simplest solution. See this article:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23665767-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-